TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 24.04
The problem is that the device works, even emits light signals indicating operation, but the system does not see available networks (the wifi tab has appeared). The wifi modem does not work and in general it is impossible to connect.
Typically, earlier I was able to run everything without problems on Ubuntu 22.04, but having installed another system on the same computer with the same device, I came to this state, and now it doesn’t even work on Ubuntu 22.04.
I used this methods:
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install

and
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8812au-1.git
cd rtl8812au-1
sudo ./dkms-install.sh

I tried the installation on all of the above systems. Doesn't work on everyone except 22.04 (it worked once on it)
Wireless Info Script:

########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 22 May 2024 13:44 MSK +0300

Booted last: 22 May 2024 00:00 MSK +0300

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

##### kernel ############################

Linux 6.8.0-31-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Apr 20 00:40:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [103c:161c]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003c Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS471 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b230 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated HP HD Webcam
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 03f0:231d HP, Inc Broadcom 2070 Bluetooth Combo
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

This system doesn't support Secure Boot

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 28672  0
sparse_keymap          12288  1 hp_wmi
platform_profile       12288  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               12288  0
wmi                    32768  3 hp_wmi,video,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp0s25' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.190.198/24 brd 192.168.190.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
       valid_lft 3590sec preferred_lft 3590sec
    inet6 fe80::3a80:632:ab1e:9451/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.190.18 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> proto dhcp src 192.168.190.198 metric 100 
192.168.190.0/24 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> proto kernel scope link src 192.168.190.198 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root        1040       1  0 13:29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.8.0-31-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:25:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:25:00.0-usb-0:1:1.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       ead36809-5af9-343b-9acf-f6793a8212e2
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.190.198/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.190.18
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.190.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.190.18, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.190.18
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.190.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_client_identifier = 01:<MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 3599
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.190.18
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.190.18
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        expiry = 1716378237
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        host_name = axolotsh-HP
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        ip_address = 192.168.190.198
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 192.168.190.18
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       routers = 192.168.190.18
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::3a80:632:ab1e:9451/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/3
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   ead36809-5af9-343b-9acf-f6793a8212e2 | Wired connection 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s25
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.8.0-31-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.13-4
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s25' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/enp0s25
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:00:19.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

grep: /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml: Permission denied
grep: /lib/netplan/00-network-manager-all.yaml: Permission denied

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp0s25   no frequency information.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s25   Interface doesn't support scanning.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  936.842673] rndis_host 3-1:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: renamed from usb0

########## wireless info END ############




Where confusing question. What actual version of Ubuntu are you trying to fix? Pick one.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit your question to include results from the wireless script

To install the driver for the TP-Link AC600 Nano Wireless USB Adapter on Ubuntu 24.04, follow these steps:

Preparations

Update the system:

Open a terminal and run:
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade


Install the necessary packages:
sudo apt install build-essential dkms git




Download the Driver

Clone the RTL8812AU driver repository (which is compatible with the AC600):
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git


Navigate to the cloned repository directory:
cd rtl8812au




Compile and Install the Driver

Add the driver to DKMS (Dynamic Kernel Module Support):
sudo dkms add .


Build and install the driver:
sudo dkms build 8812au/5.6.4.2 && sudo dkms install 8812au/5.6.4.2




Load the Driver

Load the driver module:
sudo modprobe 8812au


Verify the driver is loaded correctly:
sudo dmesg | grep 8812au




Connect to Wi-Fi

Connect to a Wi-Fi network using the Ubuntu graphical interface or nmcli (NetworkManager Command Line Interface):
nmcli device wifi list
nmcli device wifi connect "SSID" password "password"




Persistent Configuration

To ensure the driver is loaded automatically at system startup, add the module to the /etc/modules file. So edit the /etc/modules file:
sudo nano /etc/modules


Add the line 8812au at the end of the file and save it:
8812au





Conclusion:
After following these steps, your TP-Link AC600 Nano adapter should be working correctly on Ubuntu 24.04. If you encounter any issues, check the system logs with the `dmesg command and look for messages related to the driver.
Feel free to ask if you need further assistance or encounter any specific issues!
